# Unexpected azure-function timeouts on app-service-plan

Tags: azure-functions

Azure functions recently got 5 minute timeout behavior on consumption/dynamic plans.

I'm using an queue triggered function on a standard tier app service plan with AlwaysOn enabled, but I'm still seeing the timeout (after ~10mins), followed by infinite retries, despite my host.json specifying a maxDequeueCount of 1. I've tried setting functionTimeout in host.json (to 1h) but it has no impact.

Am I missing something? Is this functionality documented anywhere, and is it configurable?

I can only find multiple references to execution time being unlimited for premium & standard tier app service plans, but this doesn't match what I'm seeing.
(Runtime version: latest (~1))

Comment: Are you talking about Storage or Service Bus queues? I had this problem with a Function App listening with up to 15 Functions on corresponding Service Bus queues in parallel with a maxConcurrentCalls 16. When changing this setting to 2 or 1 the Function App was getting back to normal behavior without timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

encountered with the same issue. removed "function-timeout" property from the host file. this worked for me for functions with queue trigger in app service plan with Always-On enabled and my function was able to run for more than 30 minutes.