# How to set Infinite Timeout for Azure Function app v2.0

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-functions

I have a very long running process which is hosted using Azure Function App (though it's not recommended for long running processes) targeting v2.0. Earlier it was targeting v1.0 runtime so I didn't face any function timeout issue.

But now after updating the runtime to target v2.0, I am not able to find any way to set the function timeout to Infinite as it was in case of v1.0.

Can someone please help me out on this ?

Comment: Why are you having such a long running app? Perhaps you can find a way to break it up in smaller executions and multiple Azure Functions

Comment: The scope of breaking it down is not possible as of now. It is a continuous running process and yes function app may not be the ideal candidate for this. But I am not in a position to change it currently. So I have to live with that I have now. It was perfectly working fine with v1.0 runtime. I am looking for its alternative in v2.0 runtime.

Answer (score 10):

From your comments it looks like breaking up into smaller functions or using something other than functions isn't an option for you currently. In such case, AFAIK you can still do it with v2.0 as long as you're ready to use "App Service Plan".

The max limit of 10 minutes only applies to "Consumption Plan".

[image]

In fact, documentation explicitly suggests that if you have functions that run continuously or near continuously then App Service Plan can be more cost-effective as well.

You can use the "Always On" setting. Read about it on Microsoft Docs here.

[Azure Functions scale and hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale)

[image]

Also, documentation clearly states that default value for timeout with App Service plan is 30 minutes, but it can be set to unlimited manually.

[Changes in features and functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#changes-in-features-and-functionality)

[image]

**UPDATE**

From our discussion in comments, as null value isn't working for you like it did in version 1.x, please try taking out the "functionTimeout" setting completely.

I came across 2 different SO posts mentioning something similar and the Microsoft documentation text also says there is no real limit. Here are the links to SO posts I came across:

- [SO Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680125/unexpected-azure-function-timeouts-on-app-service-plan/46564998#46564998)
- [SO Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335646/azure-function-on-always-on-app-service-plan-times-out-with-no-functiontimeout-s/45344808#45344808)

Comment: I am running my Azure functions on App Service Plan (Standard tier) and Always On is also enabled. But after running for couple of hours, the function is getting idle and then function timeout is occurring. I tried setting the functionTimeout to null as it was in previous v1.0 but that also didn't helped.

Comment: @shyam_baidya I've edited my answer to include the link which clearly states that for v2.0 the default values is 30 mins and "You can manually change the timeout back to unlimited by using the functionTimeout setting in host.json". I understand that "null" may not be working for you with v2.0, please try to set it to a really high number as a workaround in the meanwhile. I'll also try to find what exactly should be the value (if not null) to point it to unlimited in v2.0.

Comment: @shyam_baidya please try to remove the "function-timeout" property altogether from the host.json file. I came across 2 different SO posts mentioning something similar and the Microsoft documentation text also says there is no real limit, so it's worth a try. Here are the links to SO posts I came across: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680125/unexpected-azure-function-timeouts-on-app-service-plan/46564998#46564998 and another one here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335646/azure-function-on-always-on-app-service-plan-times-out-with-no-functiontimeout-s/45344808#45344808

Comment: Thanks Rohit for sharing those SO links. I found the below github repository and what I understood is that we can't make functionTimeout to infinite. It defaults to 30 mins for App Service Plan or else the value will be set from the host.json file.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/71d607dcfa08bb8ca7fe6c974aebe3bdba20cc21/src/WebJobs.Script/Config/ScriptHostOptionsSetup.cs

Comment: @shyam_baidya ok that makes sense.. in that case going with a really high value like discussed earlier would be the work around.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to implement [Eternal orchestrations from Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations). It allows you to implement an infinite loop with dynamic intervals. Of course, you need to slightly modify your code by adding support for the stop/start function at any time (you must pass the state between calls).

```
[FunctionName("Long_Running_Process")]
public static async Task Run(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var initialState = context.GetInput<object>();
    var state = await context.CallActivityAsync("Run_Long_Running_Process", initialState);

    if (state == ???) // stop execution when long running process is completed
    {
        return;
    }

    context.ContinueAsNew(state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set an Azure Function App timeout to infinite.  I believe the longest any azure function app will consistently run is 10 minuets.  As you stated Azure functions are not meant for long running processes. You may need find a new solution for your app, especially if you will need to scale up the app at all in the future.

Comment: Actually this provision was present in v1.0 runtime but I am not able to find it for v2.0 runtime.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout

Comment: the statement is only true for Consumption Plan. see other answer regarding App Service Plan "always on"